# MagicalRecord 2.3.0/3.0 saving objects within objects

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I tried to figure it out but I couldn't find a solution to this problem. I don't understand how I can save objects within objects in the new version of magicalrecord ([MagicalRecord Docu](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Saving-Entities.md)).

What I have are two objects that point to each other. What is the best way?

Before I could easily:

```
//create both entities
myObject = [MyObject createEntity];
subObject = [SubObject createEntity];

//connect them
myObject.subObject = subObject;

//save everything
[MagicalRecord saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlockAndWait:nil];
```

How can I do it now? I tried (according to the docu):

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    myObject = [MyObject createEntityInContext:localContext];
    subObject = [SubObject createEntityInContext:localContext];
    myObject.subObject = subObject;
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
```

But this doesn't work :( (It all happens in a block.) I am glad for any advice. Maybe there is a better or more elegant way.

Comment: I don't know why you say it doesn't work. Does it get an error during save? If it does, what is it? Please check the value of `success` and `error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
- (void) myProcessWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *otherContext) {
     MyObject *myObject = [MyObject createEntityInContext:otherContext];
     SubObject *subObject = [SubObject createEntityInContext:otherContext];

     myObject.subObject = subObject;

     [otherContext saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion::^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
          [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
          bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
     }];
}
```

You can still use the defaul context:

```
- (void) myProcess {
     MyObject *myObject = [MyObject createEntity];
     SubObject *subObject = [SubObject createEntity];

     myObject.subObject = subObject;

     [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion::^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
          [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
          bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
     }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.